# WebGL verbose mode in Chrome / Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, chromium

I wish to start in the web development using WebGL technology, but I have a minor issue.
Usually, I test my applications in Chrome. I love its console which is, as far I'm concerned, better than Firebug.

However, even though a verbose mode is available in Firefox (with webgl.verbose set to true), I haven't found such a thing for Chrome. I know that there is some ways to avoid the problem by using some libraries (I've found webgl-debug.js, but some errors throw unreadable messages).

So my question is : do you know any builtin way to enable WebGL logging in Chrome / Chromium ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

chrome supports "about:gpu" url. It provides basic information on webgl and a profiler.

Else you got [WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.com/WebGL-Inspector/) which is a "An advanced WebGL debugging toolkit". In short this is a bit like the javascript console, but for WebGL

Answer (score 1):

Here is [another solution](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/) brought by latest Chrome DevTools.